# Python: Extract dimension data from dataframe string column and create columns with values for each of them

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, extract

### Hej,

I have a source file with 2 columns: ID and all_dimensions. All dimensions is a string with different "key-value"-pairs which are not the same for each id.
I want to make the keys column headers and parse the respective value if existent in the right cell.

### Example:

```
ID  all_dimensions
12  Height:2 cm,Volume: 4cl,Weight:100g
34  Length: 10cm, Height: 5 cm
56  Depth: 80cm
78  Weight: 2 kg, Length: 7 cm
90  Diameter: 4 cm, Volume: 50 cl
```

### Desired result:

```
ID  Height  Volume  Weight  Length  Depth  Diameter 
12  2 cm     4cl     100g      -      -        -
34  5 cm      -        -     10cm     -        -
56    -       -        -      -      80cm      -
78    -       -      2 kg    7 cm     -        -
90    -     50 cl     -       -      -        4 cm
```

I do have over a 100 dimensions so ideally I would like to write a for loop or something similar to not specify each column header (see code examples below)
I am using Python 3.7.3 and pandas 0.24.2.

### What have I tried already:

1) I have tried to split the data in separate columns but wasn't sure how to proceed to have each value assigned into the right header:

```
df.set_index('ID',inplace=True)
newdf = df["all_dimensions"].str.split(",|:",expand = True)
```

2) Using the initial df, I used "str.extract" to create new columns (but then I would need to specify each header):

```
df['Volume']=df.all_dimensions.str.extract(r'Volume:([\w\s.]*)').fillna('')
```

3) To resolve the problem of 2) with each header, I created a list of all dimension attributes and thought to use the list with an for loop to extract the values:

```
columns_list=df.all_dimensions.str.extract(r'^([\D]*):',expand=True).drop_duplicates()
columns_list=columns_list[0].str.strip().values.tolist()
for dimension in columns_list:
    df.dimension=df.all_dimensions.str.extract(r'dimension([\w\s.]*)').fillna('')
```

Here, JupyterNB gives me a UserWarning: "Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name" and the df looks the same as before.

Comment: Thanks for editing the sample data format, WeNYoBen!

Comment: For the warning, change: `trial.dimension` to `trial['dimension']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**: I prefer splitting several time:

```
new_series = (df.set_index('ID')
                .all_dimensions
                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                .stack()
                .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
             )

# split second time for individual measurement
new_df = (new_series.str
                    .split(':', expand=True)
                    .reset_index()
                    )

# stripping off leading/trailing spaces
new_df[0] = new_df[0].str.strip()
new_df[1] = new_df[1].str.strip()

# unstack to get the desire table:
new_df.set_index(['ID', 0])[1].unstack()
```

**Option 2**: Use `split(',|:')` as what you tried:

```
# splitting
new_series = (df.set_index('ID')
                .all_dimensions
                .str.split(',|:', expand=True)
                .stack()
                .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
             )

# concat along axis=1 to get dataframe with two columns 
# new_df.columns = ('ID', 0, 1) where 0 is measurement name
new_df = (pd.concat((new_series[::2].str.strip(), 
                     new_series[1::2]), axis=1)
            .reset_index())

new_df.set_index(['ID', 0])[1].unstack()
```

**Output**:

```
    Depth   Diameter    Height  Length  Volume  Weight
ID                      
12  NaN     NaN     2 cm    NaN     4cl     100g
34  NaN     NaN     5 cm    10cm    NaN     NaN
56  80cm    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
78  NaN     NaN     NaN     7 cm    NaN     2 kg
90  NaN     4 cm    NaN     NaN     50 cl   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard question , your string need to be `split` and your each items after split need to be convert to `dict` , then we can using `DataFrame` constructor rebuild those columns

```
d=[ [{y.split(':')[0]:y.split(':')[1]}for y in x.split(',')]for x in df.all_dimensions]
from collections import ChainMap
data = list(map(lambda x : dict(ChainMap(*x)),d))
s=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=pd.concat([df,s.groupby(s.columns.str.strip(),axis=1).first()],1)
df
Out[26]: 
   ID                       all_dimensions  Depth  ... Length  Volume Weight
0  12  Height:2 cm,Volume: 4cl,Weight:100g    NaN  ...    NaN     4cl   100g
1  34           Length: 10cm, Height: 5 cm    NaN  ...   10cm     NaN    NaN
2  56                          Depth: 80cm   80cm  ...    NaN     NaN    NaN
3  78           Weight: 2 kg, Length: 7 cm    NaN  ...   7 cm     NaN   2 kg
4  90        Diameter: 4 cm, Volume: 50 cl    NaN  ...    NaN   50 cl    NaN
[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

---

Check the columns

```
df['Height']
Out[28]: 
0     2 cm
1     5 cm
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
Name: Height, dtype: object
```

Comment: how did you load the data?

Comment: but it fails, did you use a special separator?

Comment: @Yuca adding sep '[' :-)

Comment: @Erfan here you go adding the str.strip

Comment: Thanks guys for helping out, I was going crazy on that one!
@WeNYoBen, I thought about the dict stuff and did some trials but that did not result into anything fruitable because I tried to do it into the df and there is does not accept dicts.